# Remove duplicate rows on multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
select m.movementid, m.orderid, m.pickupdate, m.pickupnotes, 
b.bin_size, b.bin_type, 
l.address, l.suburb, l.postcode, l.state, 
if(rs.run_action = 'Pick', if (r.run_state = 'Active' or r.run_state='Ready', 1, 0), 0) as active_on_pick
from bb_movement m
inner join bb_bins b on b.bin_id = m.bin_id
inner join bb_location l on l.locationid = m.locationid
inner join bb_runsheet rs on rs.movement_id = m.movementid
inner join bb_run r on r.run_id = rs.run_id
where m.mvtstate = 'Active'
order by m.locationid, m.pickupdate
```

which I want to produce a result where the active_on_pick column contains a 0 or 1 for each movementid.  A record exists in the bb_runsheet table when a given movementid is added to a bb_run
(a bb_run can have many bb_runsheet records, which primary contain a movementid)

The problem I have is that when a movement IS on a run (ie: has a bb_run record which matches the criteria and an entry in the bb_runsheet table) I get 2 rows in the result dataset - eg:

```
mvt_id active_on_pick
21     0
21     1
```

all I want is 21 and 1.  I tried subqueries and other variants (such as group by movementid) but can seem to nail it.  I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you move some of your logic into your join (changed to a LEFT JOIN), you can get the answer, moved more logic into another left join

```
select m.movementid, m.orderid, m.pickupdate, m.pickupnotes, 
b.bin_size, b.bin_type, 
l.address, l.suburb, l.postcode, l.state, 

IF(r.run_id IS NULL, 0, 1) as active_on_pick

from bb_movement m
inner join bb_bins b on b.bin_id = m.bin_id
inner join bb_location l on l.locationid = m.locationid

LEFT join bb_runsheet rs 
 ON rs.movement_id = m.movementid
    AND rs.run_action = 'Pick'

LEFT join bb_run r 
  ON r.run_id = rs.run_id
    AND (r.run_state = 'Active' or r.run_state='Ready')

where m.mvtstate = 'Active'
order by m.locationid, m.pickupdate
```

Comment: Thanks @Ag, I tried to run this query as is and get a 1241 error (running mysql 5.5.29).  Removing the 1,0) from the last and removes the error but doesn't solve the problem.  I'm not used to this syntax, but like the approach you've taken.. I'll keep hacking away...

Comment: Sorry - there is a huge typo in it

Comment: If you can, put some sample data in sqlfiddle.com.  It would make testing easier

Comment: again thanks @Ag, runs, but I get the same results as original query.  SQLFiddle?  Never used that either!.. I'll take a look right now

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46112/1 - I should add that I took out the superflous tables (bin / locations)

Comment: I continued the previous maneuver, and made the runsheet a left join with the JOIN Logic -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46112/4

Comment: That works, the logic change and join types were the key.  Thank you very much @Ag

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_Number()

```
SELECT * FROM (    
select row_number() over (order by active_on_pick desc) rn,
m.movementid, m.orderid, m.pickupdate, m.pickupnotes, 
b.bin_size, b.bin_type, 
l.address, l.suburb, l.postcode, l.state, 
if(rs.run_action = 'Pick', if (r.run_state = 'Active' or r.run_state='Ready', 1, 0), 0) 
as active_on_pick
from bb_movement m
inner join bb_bins b on b.bin_id = m.bin_id
inner join bb_location l on l.locationid = m.locationid
inner join bb_runsheet rs on rs.movement_id = m.movementid
inner join bb_run r on r.run_id = rs.run_id
where m.mvtstate = 'Active'
order by m.locationid, m.pickupdate
) SampleTable
Where rn = 1
```

Comment: row_number is on MSSQL, not MySQL